# Entity Framework when new property then auto update view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity class with 3 properties, and I used the feature in Visual Studio to automatically generate the view.

If I had a 4th property afterward, is there a way to auto update the view as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You can try using [Source Generators](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.md), but generating code for a view can become a problem in some time. You should add properties by yourself.